# Include a captcha in a Tpl Form

Tags: javascript, php, captcha

Hi I try to include a Captcha script inside a .Tpl form but if I write the correct email and not fill the captcha Simple the form jump the captcha
The form look to word and the captcha show the numbers. I try different combinations  with  onsubmit="return checkform(this);" value="{{$submit}}
but nothing look to words
any ideas please?

```
    <div class="generic-content-wrapper-styled">
<h3>{{$title}}</h3>

<p id="lostpass-desc">
{{$desc}}
</p>

<form action="lostpass" method="post" >
<div id="login-name-wrapper">
        <label for="login-name" id="label-login-name">{{$name}}</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="60" name="login-name" id="login-name" value="" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="lostpass-submit-button" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" value="{{$submit}}"/>
</div>
<!-- START CAPTCHA -->
<br>
<div class="capbox">

<div id="CaptchaDiv"></div>

<div class="capbox-inner">
Type the above number:<br>

<input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha">
<input type="text" name="CaptchaInput" id="CaptchaInput" size="15"><br>

</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<!-- END CAPTCHA -->

<div id="login-extra-end"></div>
<div id="login-submit-end"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Captcha Script

function checkform(theform){
var why = "";

if(theform.CaptchaInput.value == ""){
why += "- Please Enter CAPTCHA Code.\n";
}
if(theform.CaptchaInput.value != ""){
if(ValidCaptcha(theform.CaptchaInput.value) == false){
why += "- The CAPTCHA Code Does Not Match.\n";
}
}
if(why != ""){
alert(why);
return false;
}
}

var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';

var code = a + b + c + d + e;
document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
document.getElementById("CaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;

// Validate input against the generated number
function ValidCaptcha(){
var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('CaptchaInput').value);
if (str1 == str2){
return true;
}else{
return false;
notice( t('No valid account found.') . EOL);
                        goaway(z_root());

}
}

// Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
function removeSpaces(string){
return string.split(' ').join('');
}
</script>

</div>
```